# Unable to deploy app with nuget references on server

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-devops, nuget

I am having a hard time deploying my first .net core app with nuget references on the server. Locally, the app works absolutely fine (able to use nuget packages).

Apparently, there is no packages.config. I am using Dapper, Newtonsoft.Json, etc. Where is the project storing reference to these packages? There is no packages folder.

In the solutions folder, there is nuget.config file which for some reason is empty.

What should I add here

[image]

Comment: Hi Leo, our DevOps guy is looking into the solution you provided. I will update you as soon as possible. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Leo, sorry about our limited knowledge on building this. Please see this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5W7B.png   DevOps guy is not seeing 2.* in the dropdown. What exactly do we need to do here? Thank you

Comment: It seems you are not using Azure devops. You are using TFS? What is the version of your TFS? Or you can use nuget command line with nuget.exe with 4.0.

Comment: Yes, using TFS 2016

Comment: check my updated answer below for some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unable to deploy app with nuget references on server

That because you are using the old version nuget restore task in the build pipeline, which only supports for the package management type `packages.config` not `PackageReference`.

That the reason why the old version task ask you to provide the path to the `packages.config`. The `PackageReference` is a follow-up product, so the previous version of nuget restore task does not support it.

Check [the blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/NuGet-now-fully-integrated-into-MSBuild/) for some more details.

To resolve this issue, please use the **V2** of the nuget restore task:

[image]

Note:

- The `PackageReference` needs the nuget.exe 4.1 and above, please add
  a [NuGet tool installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/nuget?view=azure-devops) to install the nuget version above `4.1`.
- Using .NET Core restore task should be also work for this issue.

**Update:**

> Yes, using TFS 2016

Since you are using TFS 2016, you could try to use the command line to invoke the nuget.exe to restore the package instead of the nuget installer task:

[image]

Download the nuget.exe above 4.0 from the nuget.org, then set it on the TFS server.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `NuGet.config` file that points to whatever NuGet feed you're using, add it to source control, and reference it in your build.  I'll use the official feed for my example.  This feed is already present by default if you're developing using Visual Studio, which might explain why the build runs locally but not on Azure DevOps.

At the very least, your `NuGet.config` file needs to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="NuGet.org Feed" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

In .NET Core, packages are now stored globally in your User directory.  `packages.config` has been dropped in favor of the PackageReference node in a project file, so check your `csproj` to see the NuGets you're referencing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My problem is that my server doesn't have access to the internet. So I need to have all the packages in the folder containing solution before I can check in the code. Packages folder is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You should use task [dotnetcorecli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops) task which has

```
#command: 'build' # Options: build, push, pack, publish, restore, run, test, custom
```